# Игнорирование элементов с одинаковым тегом, но с разными классами

Tags: node.js, cheerio

```
<td><center><span class="image"><img src=""></span></center></td>
<td><center>test</center></td>
<td><center>test2</center></td>
```

Существует такая страничка. Три строчки с одинаковым тегом td. Каким способ можно текст строчек занести в массив, при этом, чтобы строчка с классом "image" пропускалась?

Мой код:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(body);

            const player = [];

            $('td').each(function(i, elem) {
                player[i] = $(this).text()
              });
```

Вывод: `['', 'test', 'test2']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const body = `<html><body><table><tr>
<td><center><span class="image"><img src=""></span></center></td>
<td><center>test</center></td>
<td><center>test2</center></td>
</tr></table></body></html>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(body);

const player = [];

$('td:not(:has(.image))').each(function (i, elem) {
    player[i] = $(this).text()
});

console.log(player)
```